# orkut application

Tags: database

i am a beginer in developing orkut application. can any one tell me the basics of that like how database is designed and all...

Answer (score 2):

How about the orkut documentation for developpers ?
http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/orkut/

Answer (score 2):

I do recomend you to go first to the [orkut developer forum](http://groups.google.com/group/opensocial-orkut), read the fixed topics an then go to the docs that MAX suggested. :)

The reason is that there are a lot of outdated informations in the docs. In the forum the informations are more updated and you can always ask the community if something doesn't  work. ;)